# Get Class object of class with companion object

Tags: scala

I has a class, let it be `Foo`. I also have a `Foo` companion object, like

```
object Foo {}

class Foo {}
```

In one file. At some other place of code, I need to retrieve Class object of my `Foo` class. However, when I do

```
import my.package.Foo

Foo.getClass()
```

returns Class object of companion object (`Foo$`) rather then class one. 
How can I retrieve the proper, class Class object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so using `classOf`:

```
classOf[Foo]
```